# Best way to store private key from address

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoind, private-key, mnemonic-seed

I make my own hot-wallet and wanted to know best way to store private key from address, because I need it for signing transactions.
I tried store private key in my bitcoin core node, but I realized that this is not best way. Maybe you know other way do it or how to get private key for transaction.

Comment: Why do you think private keys in bitcoin core is not the best way?

Comment: @Prayank Because, I thought that if someone gets access to bitcoin node(rpc server) then he can get private key from address.

Comment: So the problem is with server

Comment: @Prayank Yea, that's why I asked this question)
At your discretion which way is best for you?

Comment: If you can afford using several devices, you could store private keys in an air gapped cold storage device isolated from the server which exposes Bitcoin RPC. Would that work?

Comment: @Mercedes What do you mean about "isolate Bitcoin RPC server" ?
If you mean store private key in remote Bitcoin RPC wallet, I did it. I just want to know other ways to store private key

Comment: I mean have private keys in cold storage device, and to not have private keys in the node exposed through RPC. Cold storage is widely written of on the Internet.

Comment: @Mercedes I'll think about it, thanks, but I think that cold wallet it better for mobile device not for web wallet, but I can wrong)

Comment: @Prayank @Mercedes I've just looked that Bitcoin RPC have `encryptwallet`, and I'll be encrypt wallet password of user and then unlock wallet and get private key, I thinks it will be good.

Comment: A large enough Bitcoin stash on hot wallets, even password protected, is vulnerable to zero day vulnerabilities. Cold storage is a lot safer, specially if the safe room can be made free from electronic nano insects and other less futuristic intrusion menaces such as electromagnetic sniffing.

Comment: @Mercedes I know that cold wallet it's the best idea for store your keys, but for web wallet/exchange-swap it will be difficult(